# Click button with playwright

Tags: python, html, playwright

I am having difficulties with clicking on a button on a specific website with playwright. If I am not mistaken there is no button specified in the code and the *locator* function does not seem to work. The code given on the website:

```
<div class="loginformbutton loginformbutton-top loginformbutton-bottom">
                        <div id="buttonArea" class="m-align">
                            <div class="loginBtn" id="btn_outerverify" tabindex="0">
                                <span id="submitDataverify">Log In</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: What locator did you use? `Click` works on anything that has a `click` handler. Nowadays this can be anything. There may be a `click` handler attached to any element with the `loginBtn` class

Comment: Please share a [mcve]. This isn't enough context to help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved due to the setup of the website. Instead of clicking the button, I used a function to press enter which logs you in.

```
import playwright.sync_api
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import time

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch(headless = False, slow_mo = 50)
    page = browser.new_page ()
    page.goto("YOUR URL")
    page.fill("input#username", "YOUR USERNAME")
    page.fill("input#value", "YOUR PASSWORD")
    
    page.keyboard.press("Enter")
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Why not call `Click` on the correct element? Locators work. You can test them in your browser's Developer tools. An alternative is to have Playwright itself record your actions and check what code is generated